# Whats the proper way to handle strcpy's return type

Tags: c, strcpy

I created a program which at some point turned to be a buggy one and I can not find a good way to handle situations like in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_user_name( char *const dest, char *const src );
char *foo( char *variable ); /// foo() returns NULL

int main( void )
{
    char arr[256]      = { 0 };
    char buffer[ 256 ] = { 0 };
    char *const ptr    = foo( arr ); /// foo() returned NULL here

    if ( get_user_name( buffer, ptr ) == 0 ) /// get_user_name, should here return 0
    {
        printf("NULL returned from get_user_name()\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else
    {
        printf( "Everithing is OK" );
    }
}

int get_user_name( char *const dest, char *const src )
{
    char *ret = strcpy( dest, src ); /// Here Segfault happens
    /// There is no return here because of above Segfault
    if ( ret == NULL )
    {
        return 0;
    }else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

char *foo( char *variable )
{
    if ( strlen( variable) < 1 )
    {
        return NULL;    /// Here will return NULL because there is no Length
    }
    /// Some code here ...
    return variable;
}
```

Here is use a demo function which returns `NULL` to explain my problem.
I was thinking to check `src` before past it to `strcpy` but I really cannot understand why `strcpy` returns `dest` without check if `src` is `NULL` or not.

Why does this happens because I see that `strcpy` manual say only about the return of `dest` and nothing if fails:

```
   RETURN VALUE
   The strcpy() and strncpy() functions return a pointer to the destination string dest.
```

Comment: *but I really cannot understand why strcpy returns dest without check if src is NULL or not.* - because it says in the standard that it expects a c-string, not a `NULL`. And I bet `strcpy()` most times won't return anything but crash almost instantly.

Comment: `strcpy` causes the abort of your program because one of the parameters is null. Check before calling.

Comment: @Swordfish I all ready pointed to segfault in the Question. And I also know what the standard say. Expecting something which is a string and relying on that that there will be no NULL without checking, from my side it does not make it the best function. I do know that as`c` programmer I need to check everything against `NULL` but this is not my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handle the situation by first checking the parameters are not null. For example:

```
int get_user_name( char *dest, char *const src )
{
    char *ret;
    if (dest==0 || src==0) return 0;
    strcpy( dest, src );
    return 1;
}
```

Note also that `dest` cannot be `const` because it is written to.

Comment: Well, that means that `strcpy` works after I know 100% that `dest` and `src` are OK. Thank you